# "Translate" C++ QImage object to Python using Boost library

Tags: python, c++, qt, boost

I'm writing image manipulator for computer vision project. All GUI I have decided to make in python and algorithms implementation in C++.
My C++ Image class has function toQImage, that should return the result that will be represented in GUI.
The problem is that I am unable to return QImage object to python using Boost, getting bunch of errors and can't realize what I am doing wrong.

I have read that in such case I should use return_value_policy:

```cpp
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(image_manipulator) {
    class_<Image, boost::noncopyable>("Image",no_init)
        .def("toQImage", &Image::toQImage, return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>())
        .def("height", &Image::height)
        .def("width", &Image::width)
    ;

    class_<JpegImage, bases<Image>, boost::noncopyable>("JpegImage",
        init<char *>())
    ;
}
```

Here the function itself:

```cpp
const QImage& Image::toQImage() {
    return img; // const QImage& img =  QImage();
}
```

It compiles, but during execution returns:
`TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: QImage`

I googled the problem, but suggestions confused me even more. Workarounds and easier solutions are welcome!

Comment: C++, Qt, Boost, Python... I guess that you should exclude something from this list. For example, there is a native Qt to Python interface: why should you use boost instead? Anyway, the toImage method creates a local variable and returns a reference to the local. That is definitely wrong without regarding the rest of the technologies.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov, I want to make image manipulations in C++ and represent result in PyQt. About local variable, you are right, but still it returned me not a segfault.

Comment: @AntonRak If you want to use C++ in PyQt you must use SIP

Comment: @eyllanesc, unfortunately, it seems that it's the only way